# three360: change the text of TTTableControlItem dynamically

Tags: iphone, three20, tableview

Is there a way to change the text of a TTTableControlItem cell dynamically?

basically, I have a cell that would lead to another view. once I am done with the otherview, it'll have text bring over to the first view on which I want to use the new text to update the text of the cell.

Is it achievable?